# Could not find file 'obj\Debug\Program.exe.manifest'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, manifest, publish

Apologies if this has been answered before.

Something happened to my VS2010 SP1 VB.NET environment. I have been successfully working on, compiling and publishing project A via ClickOnce for a while, and then tried to publish project B, and received the error:

Could not find file 'obj\Debug\Program.exe.manifest' in file microsoft.common.targets. When I look at the microsoft.common.targets file, i receive > 101 warnings.

The Help tells me its error MSBuild Error MSB3113.

Now ALL projects behave in the same way, including the one that I was publishing.

Things I have tried:

Create new project in new location. same error during publish.

I moved both projects to a different machine, and both publish without problem.

I reinstalled VS2010 from scratch into a different location on the problem machine, and the error re-appears (problem machine is Vista, ok one is Windows7 prof).

Tried every variation of deployment, unsigned, signed etc. All projects are in VB.NET and it is unclear how to turn off the manifest inclusion via the VS2010 settings. I have tried doing this via changing the project information in the .vbproj file to

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateManifests>false</GenerateManifests>
</PropertyGroup>
```

without effect.

The project occasionally build successfully, but then fails to publish. The pattern to this I have not yet fully understood.

Any advice appreciated

Peter

Comment: Usually when things are hard to pinpoint reset to default of EVERYTHING works best. Reinstall Visual Studio, if that doesn't help reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to delete the current manifest, and the generate a new one per the instructions found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766454.aspx

Or, alternatively,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235229%28v=vs.80%29.aspx